# How to set a different input method for each app window

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, input-languages

How can I have a different input method for each app window on windows 8. When I change input language to `ENG` all app window also uses this method and I don't want that. Like windows 7 that has a different input method for this purpose. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First, you need to access the Control Panel. There are several ways to open it. 
   You can right-click at the bottom left of the screen, and then choose Control Panel from the list. 
   Alternatively, you can access it from the Charm bar. Move your mouse to the bottom right of the screen, and then choose Settings from the slide-out bar.
   You can also launch it from the Computer tab in the Explorer window.
2. In the Control Panel window, find the Language option. Use the search feature if you have trouble finding it.
3. Once you are in the Language section, click on the Advanced settings option, which is located on the left side of the window.
4. Finally, find the Switching input methods section, and turn on the Let me set a different input method for each app window option to be able to configure input method for each app.
5. When you are done, click the Save button to preserve the changes.
6. With the option enabled, go to the app for which you want to use a different input method, click on an input field, and then switch the input using the language bar.
7. Later, if you want to use a universal input method for all apps, simply turn off the Let me set a different input method for each app window option.

Comment: What is the method to do this on win 7 ?

Answer (score 10):

Update for Windows 10 at least 1809:
Switcher ***Let me set a different input method for each app window*** was moved to

> Settings -> Time&Language -> Language -> Related Settings: Spelling,
>   typing, & keyboard settings -> More keyboard settings: Advanced
>   keyboard settings

Comment: Microsoft moved it again... Settings > Time & Language > Region & language > Advanced keyboard settings

Comment: ...and again: in Windows 10 21H2 it's at Settings -> Time & Language -> Language -> Keyboard -> "Let me use a different input method for each app window" ([from user Sergey](https://superuser.com/a/1732342/272824)).

Comment: In Windows 11 23H2 the location is Settings > Time & Language > Typing > Advanced  keyboard settings