# Windows Language Input Change on Keyboard not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, input-languages

Keyboard Language Input change is not working on Windows 10. How can I fix? Even Change with Alt-Shift does not work. I also noticed sometimes notepad opens up in Korean, even though I am using English or Japanese.

Just learned its "Change Key Sequence", last picture below, and using that hotkey does not work (Ctrl-shift, grave hotkey `).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would uninstall the other languages then reinstall them.

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1340511/8672) on how to totally eradicate unneeded keyboard layouts. If this changes nothing, then test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Question: Does this also happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Try a switcher *Let me set a different input method for each app window*, see  https://superuser.com/questions/772698/